# Why doesn't Vue3 display this getter's value?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I have a object that includes this model:

```js
export class Coordinate {
  file: string;
  row:  number;
  public get toString(): string{
    return `${this.file}${this.row}`;
  }
  constructor(file: string, row:  number){
    this.file = file;
    this.row = row;
  }
}
```

I push through custom components' props.

1. This displays: `function toString() { [native code] }`

   ```html
     <p> {{ myObject.coordinate.toString }} </p>
   ```
2. This displays: `[object Object]`

   ```html
     <p> {{ myObject.coordinate.toString() }} </p>
   ```
3. If I switch it up to this:

   ```js
     asString = () => `${this.file}${this.file}`;
   ```

.. and call it like, "`myOject.coordinate.asString`," it returns `undefined`.  If I call it like `.asString()`, typescript lets it slide, but it throws an error in the console.

4. This displays fine, but leaves me with a feeling of defeat:

```html
<p> {{ myObject.coordinate.file }}{{ myObject.coordinate.row }} </p>
```

Comment: It's unclear why toString is a getter at all.

Comment: Instead of toString, maybe try asString? Since javascript objects already have a toString method.